# PL/SQL: Adding minutes to timestamp increases milliseconds only

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm having an issue where adding minutes to my timestamp object only increases the milliseconds. I'm using PL/SQL

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE
V_DUEDATE         TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
SELECT
CASE
  WHEN 1 = 1
  THEN to_timestamp('03/FEB/2016 14:02:08.50948', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF') + 15/1440
  ELSE to_timestamp('03/FEB/2016 14:02:08.50948', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')
END
INTO V_DUEDATE
FROM DUAL;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('new duedate:'||TO_CHAR(V_DUEDATE, 'DD/MON/YYYY   HH24:MM:SS.SSSSS'));
END;
```

The output of the above CASE statement returns `03/FEB/2016 14:02:08.51428`, an increase of 480 ms.

But when I run the following, the correct increase is made:

```
select to_timestamp('03/FEB/2016 14:02:08.50948'),  to_timestamp('03/FEB/2016 14:02:08.50948') + 15/1440 from dual;
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong please as I need to use the first sample code in my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in your first post, you appear to be converting the date to HH24:**MM**:SS.SSSSS rather than HH24:**MI**:SS.SSSSS. So you're showing months, not minutes.
Not sure why it's adding MS at all though, since you're trying to add 15 minutes. But it shouldn't matter

Comment: Ha! been looking at this way too long. It was indeed the minute formatting that was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

`to_timestamp('03/FEB/2016 14:02:08.50948', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF') + 15/1440`

then the `TIMESTAMP` value is implicitly converted to a `DATE` value. By this you loose the fractional seconds, so the result is "03/FEB/2016 14:17:08.**00000**"

Better use

```
to_timestamp('03/FEB/2016 14:02:08.50948', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF') 
   + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE
```

or

```
to_timestamp('03/FEB/2016 14:02:08.50948', 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF') 
   + 15 * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
```